# Combining the results of three queries into one dataset cross Apply or join

Tags: sql, cross-apply

How can I combine the results of three queries into one dataset? Cross Apply or join?

```
create table tbl_A
(
Dept varchar(5),
DocCountA int
);

create table tbl_b
(
Dept varchar(5),
DocCountB int
);

create table tbl_c
(
Dept varchar(5),
DocCountC int
);

insert into tbl_A
values ('XX',12),('YY',14),('ZZ',16)

insert into tbl_b
values ('XX',20),('YY',25),('ZZ',27)

insert into tbl_c
values ('XX',30),('YY',35)

select * from tbl_A  
select * from tbl_B  
select * from tbl_C  

**tbl_A**  
Dept    DocCountA  
XX  12  
YY  14  
ZZ  16  


**tbl_B**  
Dept    DocCountB  
XX  20   
YY  25    
ZZ  27  

**tbl_C**  
Dept    DocCountC  
XX  30    
YY  35
```

**Result**

```
Dept DocCountA DocCountB DocCountC  
XX  
YY  
ZZ
```

Table C has two results ZZ will be blank

**this works using two queries** **Three will be great!**

select * from tbl_A A
cross apply
(
select B.DocCountB from tbl_b B
Where B.Dept=A.Dept
) sod

Answer (score 2):

A left join on each table will allow you to get all 3 departments and the counts if they exist.

```
select
  a.dept, DocCountA, DocCountB, DocCountC
from
  tbl_a a
  left join tbl_b b on a.dept = b.dept
  left join tbl_c c on a.dept = c.dept
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f82e9/1)

Comment: More join options: If a record may not exist in TableA for a Dept do a `full outer join`.  If all three tables are guaranteed to have a record for each Dept do an `inner join`.  If guaranteed in one (or more) tables but not others, `from` or `inner join` the tables which will have records first, then `left outer join` those which may not next.

Comment: many thanks! the three queries will be built up using derived queries and pivot.The results will be like what you get in the tables above...

Comment: @winchmore glad we could help. Please be sure to mark answers and upvote when able. Good luck!

Comment: this works using two queries Three will be great!  

select * from tbl_A A  
cross apply  
(  
select B.DocCountB from tbl_b B  
Where B.Dept=A.Dept  
) sod

Comment: @winchmore, I dont understand, are you saying that my solution works or not?